# Is it possible to change the auto format shortcut in netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, ide, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I know that you can auto-format your code in netbeans by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, but is there a way to change this key combination to something else, to bind it to some othr keys?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Answer is yes. Go to Tools -> Options. You'll get the "Options" pop-up window - choose the "Keymap" tab and type the "Format" into the Search field:

[image]

Then push the "..." button...